# C# error cannot convert sytem.text.regularexpressions.match to string

Tags: c#, regex

The following block of code captures text from an HTML page, but I get the compile error on the following line:

```
St = Regex.Match(St, @"(?i)(?<= |^)order(?= |$) (?i)(?<= |^)Term (?i)(?<= |^)oF [0-9]* (?i)(?<= |^)years (?<= |^)or (?<= |^)Longer");
```

**The code Block**:

```
 if (textordernode.InnerHtml.Contains("Order Term"))
                {
                    String St = textordernode.InnerHtml;

                    St = St.Replace(@"\r", "");
                    St = St.Replace(@"\n", "");
                    St = Regex.Replace(St, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", " ").Trim();
                    St = Regex.Match(St, @"(?i)(?<= |^)order(?= |$) (?i)(?<= |^)Term (?i)(?<= |^)oF [0-9]* (?i)(?<= |^)years (?<= |^)or (?<= |^)Longer");

                    int pFrom = St.IndexOf("Order Term of ") + "Order Term of ".Length;
                    int pTo = St.LastIndexOf("or longer");
                    try
                    {
                        textorderterm = St.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom) + "or longer";
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        textorderterm = "";
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
```

Could I get some help with this please?

Comment: `Regex.Match` returns a `Match` object, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Regex.Match` returns a `Match` object; you need to call `.Value` on the returned `Match` object to get the matched substring.

e.g.:

`St = Regex.Match(St, @"(?i)(?<= |^)order(?= |$) (?i)(?<= |^)Term (?i)(?<= |^)oF [0-9]* (?i)(?<= |^)years (?<= |^)or (?<= |^)Longer").Value;`

Comment: ....Thank you for the assist.